# Lightning Controller window.open();

Tags: lightning, javascript, controller, javascript-remoting, javascript-controller

When I use `window.open();` in my lightning controller, it opens the URL but at the end of the salesforce's url. It does open in a new tab which is what I want but the url is confusing me.

For example, if my URL is "www.google.com"; `window.open()` is pushing the url into: "https://mydevenviornment--dev4.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Opportunity/0061h00000Aq3z7AAB/www.google.com"

What gives? Shouldn't it just be opening the URL in its own tab and solely as `www.google.com`?

Here is the code:

```
({
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.Spinner", true);
    let action = component.get('c.callExpress'),
    recordId = component.get('v.recordId');
    action.setParam('opptyId', recordId);
        action.setCallback(this, function(result) {
            try {
                let state = result.getState();
                if (state === 'SUCCESS') { 
                    let expressURL = result.getReturnValue(); 
                    var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
                    dismissActionPanel.fire();
                    window.open(expressURL); //expressURL is www.google.com
                } else if (state === 'ERROR') {
                    var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
                    dismissActionPanel.fire();
                    var errors = result.getError();
                    alert(errors[0].message);
                }
            } catch(e) {
                console.log('e: ' + e);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Comment: shouldnt you be using navigation events instead?

Comment: when I use navigation events, it still generates the weird URL but also populates the URL in a salesforce sub tab rather than a new browser tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's expected. If you don't include the fully qualified URL, window.open assumes you meant "open a URL on the current domain." To open the URL correctly, it should be in the form of `https://www.google.com/`.

Comment: thank you. it was the `https://` I was missing. this worked

Comment: @sfdcfox is this best practice ?

Answer (score 0):

Could You please provide what exactly you are returning from server side code. Looks like you are appending Opportunity Id to URL as you are passing it as parameter to you method.